# Can I use Admob without uploading at Play Store in 2020?

Tags: android, admob

I have created an app but it is only for Huawei App Gallery, so its not linkable to Play Store. Ad units have been created and implemented, test ads works well, but when I still after 24hours since ad units creation trying the production ad units I getting the following error:

> No fill from ad server.
>   Failed to load ad: 3

Comment: I would also want to know this. I am experiencing the same behaviour.

Comment: I am also getting error:
I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3